# Having issues with two Excel formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

### This is my first time asking a question here, but I have two formulas that I'm not really sure why they aren't working.

The first issue I'm having is with this formula:

`=MAX(IF(C46:C51<80,B46:B51))`

Any reason that this formula returns #VALUE! I'm supposed to find the max value of data in column B so long as the data in column C is less than 80. By the way, this is the dataset for that formula: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBs2f.jpg)

---

Then I'm having issues with VLOOKUP on two questions, that are related I have a large dataset on a separate worksheet. I need to VLOOKUP someone's name to find a value associated with that name. The problem is that their name comes up multiple times. The formula I have for it so far is:

`=VLOOKUP('PDR DATA'!E80,'PDR DATA'!A4:V119,15,FALSE)`

Where 'PDR DATA'!E80 is the first instance of the person's name appearing. However, using FALSE with VLOOKUP returns #N/A, but if I use TRUE it returns the very last value from column 15 even though the name is different from what I'm searching for. This is a sample of the dataset for this formula: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SZIo.jpg)

I'm lost here and don't know where to turn.

Comment: With the second item what are you looking to find the details of the first record, last?

Comment: SER and Rank of the employee name.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure why to say the one would while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one the issue you have is likely you are not entering it as an array formula. The easy solution is to make sure you press Ctrl&Shift along with Enter; that will add an additional set of bracket { }. In the screen cap below the first one works

[image]

In the second one without the array the error you mention comes up.

[image]